# Open Panel as ToolStrip MenuItem after click on menu C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, panel, menuitem

There is special menu item in **Visual Studio Express 2013.**
It looks like  a`Panel` opened after a click on `MenuItem`. For example:

[image]

How can I create **"panel menu item"** like this for my `MenuStrip`, connected to `MenuItem`? It is only a standard `MenuItem` and standard hidden `Panel` with dynamic position based on the `Form` borders? Or is it a modified `MenuItem` to contain Graphics and Uri?

I searched for something like that, but I can not find how to create Panel inside a `ToolStrip`, and I don't know if should I create a plain `Panel` with menu, or there is a solution somewhere (Custom component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, you can use a ToolStripControlHost to hold a Panel or a UserControl:

The control to show in the pop-up:

```
var panel = new Panel() {
  BackColor = Color.White,
  MinimumSize = new Size(150, 72),
  Size = MinimumSize,     
};
panel.Paint += (s, e) => {
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Pop-up Panel",
  SystemFonts.DefaultFont, panel.ClientRectangle,
  Color.Black, Color.Empty,
  TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
};
```

The ToolStrip controls to show the panel:

```
  var hostTool = new ToolStripControlHost(panel) {
    Padding = Padding.Empty,
    Margin = Padding.Empty
  };

  var downButton = new ToolStripDropDownButton("Panel Menu") {
    Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right,
    DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text,
    DropDownDirection = ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowLeft,
  };

  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)downButton.DropDown).ShowCheckMargin = false;
  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)downButton.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = false;
  downButton.DropDown.AutoSize = false;
  downButton.DropDown.Size = new Size(panel.Width + 12, panel.Height + 4);
  downButton.DropDown.Items.Add(hostTool);
  var tool = new ToolStrip();
  tool.Items.Add(downButton);
  this.Controls.Add(tool);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is perfectly fine.